# Nativescript: IllegalArgumentException in buildMetadata gradle build step

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When I add the plugin "nativescript-image-cache-it" and build the my project (`tns run android`), I get the following error message:

```
:buildMetadata
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.squareup.picasso.ContentStreamRequestHandler conflict: ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/2.5.2/7446d06ec8d4f7ffcc53f1da37c95f200dcb9387/picasso-2.5.2.jar and ~/git/nativeTest/spotwild-app/node_modules/nativescript-image-cache-it/platforms/android/picasso-2.5.2.jar
    at com.telerik.metadata.ClassRepo.cacheJarFile(ClassRepo.java:21)
    at com.telerik.metadata.Builder.build(Builder.java:39)
    at com.telerik.metadata.Generator.main(Generator.java:44)
:buildMetadata FAILED
```

It tried almost everything (so I got no more ideas what to do to solve the problem):

- tns platform remove android -> tns platform add android
- remove folder ~/.gradle/caches
- remove folder platforms/android/build
- tns platform android clean
- installed different versions of android apks and tried the build with them
- deleted node_modules folder and cleared npm cache (with `npm cache clean`)

When I remove the local picasso-2.5.2.jar (the one in the plugin folder; after a failed build) it's working fine, but it seems there are missing resource values, which are there without the plugin like the "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY".
It looks like it's some kind of strange caching problem.

My current setup:

- Nativescript 2.3
- Android SDK 23
- Android Build-Tools 23.0.3
- Android Platform Tools 25
- Android SDK Tools 25.2.2
- Android Support Repository 39
- Google Play Services 37
- Google Repository 38

Any ideas, any thoughts? thanks in advance

Comment: Try also to delete `node_modules` folder and to clear cache using `npm cache clear`

Comment: @NikolayTsonev Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue eventually?